# Positioning of Search Bar

Tags: css, search, web, squarespace

I have inserted a search bar by using my websites code injection points and now trying to re position it below my site tag line. Below in an screenshot of what I am trying to accomplish.

My website is www.jobspark.ca

```
<script type="text/javascript"   
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#banner-area").prepend("<div id='banner-tagline'>Your British Columbia and Alberta Job Search</div>");
});
</script>
<div class="positionedSearch"></div>
```

[image]

Current CSS for the search bar includes

```
.positionedSearch {
width: 400px;
height: 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest actually putting it in the HTML where you want it placed, as opposed to positioning it from another place...

You can use:

```
.positionedSearch {
    width: 400px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 40%;
    top: 330px;
}
```

This only works for the full screen media query. Needs to be adjusted for the smaller screens.

Like I said, it would be much better just to place it in that relative area via the JS.. then you can avoid using absolute positioning.

**Based on your other question:**

Find this line in your CSS and modify it to this:

```
.sqs-search-ui-button-wrapper {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.66);
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. Can you show me how you would insert it into the html.

Comment: You would add this into the stylesheet.

Comment: From looking at my code at the very top can you see where the <div class="positionedSearch"></div> needs to be placed? I tried a few different areas and did not work

Comment: @ChrisS Have you added the above CSS to your stylesheet. It would have worked.

Comment: Only issue I see is that I was going to add a transparent black background to the text and search bar. Is there a way I can do this so that the tag line as well as the search bar have the background?

Comment: Not sure if that makes any sense.

Comment: @ChrisS Alright - see my update. I am pretty sure that's what you wanted.

Comment: Ok thanks. You have any idea on how to fix it for mobile. By adding in the search bar there is has messed things up

Comment: @ChrisS Yea, I know - I said it would do that. You are going to need to modify it for each media query

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
.positionedSearch {
    width: 400px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```